# Best way to use slug for querying Prisma without react hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, prisma

### Get post by ID ( slug ) from prisma when `getStaticProps()` before page build

So the issue is that I cannot use React hook in `getStaticProps`. I was going to get slug names with useRouter, then query for post by using the slug (postID), but I learned that I cannot run prisma inside of body components. Then I learned that I can use `getStaticProps` and `getStaticPaths` to query the post by its ID before build time.
How do I get N levels of slug names in `getStaticProps`?.

### Code

`/post/[...slugs].tsx`

My url looks like: `localhost:3000/post/postID/PostTitle`

such as `localhost:3000/post/b513-ad29e3cc67d9/Post%20Title`

```js
import { Post, PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';
import { GetStaticPaths, GetStaticProps } from 'next';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

type postByIdProps = {
  postById: Post
}

export default function PostDetail({postById}: postByIdProps) {

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        {postById.title}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export const getStaticProps = async(context: any)=>{
// I can't ues React Hook here, but I don't know how to get slug name without the hook.
  const router = useRouter(); 
  const slugs: any = router.query.slugs;
  const postId = slugs?.[0].toString()
//Prisma
  const prisma = new PrismaClient()
  const postById = prisma.post.findUnique({
    where: {
      postId: postId,
    },
  })

  return postById
}


export const getStaticPaths: GetStaticPaths<{ slug: string }> = async () => {

  return {
      paths: [], //indicates that no page needs be created at build time
      fallback: 'blocking' //indicates the type of fallback
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked fro me, but if someone can improve this code, more than welcome.

[How to Build a Fullstack App with Next.js, Prisma, and PostgreSQL](https://vercel.com/guides/nextjs-prisma-postgres)

### code

```js
import { Post } from '@prisma/client';
import { GetStaticPaths, GetStaticProps } from 'next';
import prisma from '../api/prisma';

type postByIdProps = {
  post: Post
}

export default function PostDetail({post}: postByIdProps) {
  console.log("Post here,", post)
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        {post.title}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export const getStaticProps = async({params}: any)=>{
  const postId = params.slugs[0] //gets post's ID
  const post = await prisma.post.findUnique({
    where:{
      postId: String(postId)
    },
  })

  return {
    props:{
      post
    }
  }
}

export const getStaticPaths: GetStaticPaths<{ slug: string }> = async () => {

  return {
      paths: [], //indicates that no page needs be created at build time
      fallback: 'blocking' //indicates the type of fallback
  }
}
```